# Converter captura ActualWidth de control antes de establecer sus valores binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

tengo un problema que no puedo resolver.

Estoy aplicando un estilo para TabItem:

```
<Style x:Key="llave" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <conv:TabItemContentToPath01Converter x:Key="TabItemContentToPath01Converter"/>
                    <conv:TabItemContentToPath02Converter x:Key="TabItemContentToPath02Converter"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                <Grid>
                    <Path x:Name="pthGrafico" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="{Binding ElementName=gridCuerpo, Converter={StaticResource TabItemContentToPath01Converter}}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure IsClosed="False" StartPoint="0,0" Segments="{Binding ElementName=gridCuerpo, Converter={StaticResource TabItemContentToPath02Converter}}"/>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        </Path.LayoutTransform>
                    </Path>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="TabItemTopBorder" Height="0" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="{Binding ElementName=gridCuerpo, Converter={StaticResource TabItemContentToPath01Converter}}" />

                    <Grid x:Name="gridCuerpo">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="stpContenedor" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Tag}" Margin="6 0" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}" Margin="0 0 4 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Button x:Name="btnCerrar" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="borderCerrar" CornerRadius="100" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="4">
                                        <Path Data="M0,0 L8,8 M8,0 L0,8" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#3C4043" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 1 0 0"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E8EAED" TargetName="borderCerrar"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="gridCuerpo">
                        <!--<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>-->
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="pthGrafico">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#eaeaea"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="pthGrafico">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Y este es mi converter:

```
public class TabItemContentToPath01Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness(0, 0, -((Grid)value).ActualHeight, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TabItemContentToPath02Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ps = new PathSegmentCollection(4);
        Grid cp = (Grid)value;

        double h = cp.ActualHeight + 10;
        double w = cp.ActualWidth + 2; // AQUI ESTA CAPTURANDO EL WIDTH ANTES DE CARGAR EL BINDING DE IMAGE Y TEXTBLOCK

        ps.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(1, 0.7 * h), true));
        ps.Add(new BezierSegment(new Point(1, 0.9 * h), new Point(0.1 * h, h), new Point(0.3 * h, h), true));

        ps.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(w, h), true));
        ps.Add(new BezierSegment(new Point(w + 0.6 * h, h), new Point(w + h, 0), new Point(w + h * 1.3, 0), true));

        return ps;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Ahora este es el control:

```
<TabItem x:Class="Proyecto.Presentacion.tab__general___usuario"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proyecto.Presentacion"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{StaticResource llave}" Header="Contenido del tab" Tag="Imagenes/16xcerrar.png">
</TabItem>
```

Y este es el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, el width de la primera pestaña (colo blanco) no llega a tomar el 100% (IMAGE + TEXTBLOCK + BUTTON), he hecho pruebas y siempre es 40 (es como si capturara el valor antes de ejecutarse el BINDING)

**Importante:** Si en el estilo pongo los valores de forma directa, todo funciona OK.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stpContenedor" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="Imagenes/16xcerrar.png" Margin="6 0" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Contenido del tab" Margin="0 0 4 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Y este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En conclusión mi problema es en el código c#, ¿alguna sugerencia?
Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Me parece una pregunta interesante. Podrías explicar que efecto es exactamente el que esperas conseguir?

Comment: Hola @Pikoh gracias por tu comentario, lo que quiero hacer es personalizar el diseño del TabItem (quitar el diseño básico por uno mas vistoso, algo así como las pestañas del chrome), ya tengo el diseño pero mi problema es el width (que no completa el total del icono + texto, es decir sale cortado).

Comment: te animas a hacer un [mcve], a ver si entre varios podemos chequearlo?

Comment: es necesario un conversor? o puede ser un binding directo?

Comment: Hola, edite el post explicando mejor.

Comment: @pedroPG la pregunta se entiende perfectamente. Estoy tratando de reproducir el problema, a ver si consigo darte una solución cuando tenga tiempo de analizarlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tras algunas pruebas, voy a proponer una solución.

Lo primero, por lo que he comprobado, parece que el problema se basa en pasar el `Grid` al converter en lugar de pasar directamente las propiedades.

Si le hacemos un binding a la propiedad `ActualHeight` en lugar de al `Grid` a la hora de pasarlo al converter, la propiedad actualiza correctamente el ancho. Pero como en tu Converter `TabItemContentToPath02Converter` necesitas dos propiedades (`ActualHeight` y `ActualWidth`), lo que debemos usar es un `MultiBinding` con un `MultiValueConverter`.

En resumen, el estilo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```vb
<Style x:Key="llave" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <local:TabItemContentToPath01Converter x:Key="TabItemContentToPath01Converter"/>
                    <local:TabItemContentToPath02Converter x:Key="TabItemContentToPath02Converter"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                <Grid x:Name="gridCuerpo2">
                    <Path x:Name="pthGrafico" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="{Binding ElementName=gridCuerpo2,Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource TabItemContentToPath01Converter}}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure IsClosed="False" StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TabItemContentToPath02Converter}">
                                            <Binding ElementName="gridCuerpo" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                            <Binding ElementName="gridCuerpo2" Path="ActualHeight" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        </Path.LayoutTransform>
                    </Path>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="TabItemTopBorder" Height="0" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="{Binding ElementName=gridCuerpo,Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource TabItemContentToPath01Converter}}" />

                    <Grid x:Name="gridCuerpo">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="stpContenedor" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Tag}" Margin="6 0" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}" Margin="0 0 4 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Button x:Name="btnCerrar" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="borderCerrar" CornerRadius="100" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="4">
                                        <Path Data="M0,0 L8,8 M8,0 L0,8" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#3C4043" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 1 0 0"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E8EAED" TargetName="borderCerrar"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="gridCuerpo">
                        <!--<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>-->
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="pthGrafico">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#eaeaea"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="pthGrafico">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#dddddd"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Como puedes ver, he puesto nombre al `Grid` que contiene todo (`gridCuerpo2`), para así acceder a la altura de la pestaña y no la del `Grid` interno que contiene el texto.

Vamos ahora con el código del converter. Como verás, he modificado ambos para que reciban un value de tipo `double` en lugar de un `Grid` como tú tenías:

```
public class TabItemContentToPath01Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness(0, 0, -(double)value, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TabItemContentToPath02Converter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ps = new PathSegmentCollection(4);

        double h = (double)values[1];
        double w = (double)values[0] *0.9; 

        ps.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(0, 0.7 * h), true));
        ps.Add(new BezierSegment(new Point(0, 0.9 * h), new Point(0.1 * h, h), new Point(0.3 * h, h), true));

        ps.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(w, h), true));
        ps.Add(new BezierSegment(new Point(w + 0.6 * h, h), new Point(w + h, 0), new Point(w + h * 1.3, 0), true));

        return ps;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Verás que he modificado un poco los valores y estoy reduciendo un poco el ancho de la pestaña que se le pasa (multiplicando por 0.9) ya que si no excede un poco el ancho que se le pasa, y la pestaña reacciona creciendo incontroladamente.

Por último, una captura del resultado final de este código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible que haya que afinar algo, pero espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Quedo perfecto, muchas gracias. Aún estoy incursionando en el wpf y aun hay muchas cosas que desconozco. Gracias y saludos ¡¡¡